# List view getting stuck and the animation is not smooth when displaying images from server

Tags: java, android

I am displaying images in Listview using BaseAdapter.

It's displaying images from an url, and when I'm scrolling it's getting slow at loading time.

So it was sticking and the animation isn't smooth.

Can you please give a solution for this?

Comment: can you give some code?

Answer (score 1):

if thats the case then loading images from URL might become slow as it depends on the network,

You can load images in background and on UI part you can show a spinner with some text such as `Loading`

This might ease the UI freezing part.

Comment: ok.Is it possible to use catch memory?

Comment: didnt got your question!!!

Comment: How to use catch memory for download load the Images from server?